# Rails view not displaying partial - "response has no matching <turbo-frame id="events"> element"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hotwire

I've got an index page with a search which mostly works, aside from when there are no results, which is when I get the error:-

```
response has no matching <turbo-frame id="events"> element
```

I don't get this when there are search results.  Do I need to specify a partial to render in my index action, when results are empty?  Why isn't this being evaluated in my view?

index.html.erb

```
  <div id="events-wrapper">
    <% if @events.any? %>
      <%= render "events", events: @events %>
    <% else %>
      <%= render "no_events" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

_events.html.erb

```
<%= turbo_frame_tag "events" do %>
  <%= render collection: @events, partial: 'event' %>
  <%= raw pagy_bootstrap_nav(@pagy) %>
<% end %>
```

_no_events.html.erb

```
<div class="no-events-notice alert alert-primary">
   No events found
</div>
```

events_controller.rb index action

```
  def index
    @pagy, @events = pagy(find_events(filter_params))
  end
```

Basically my search works fine, but when there are no results - my `no_events` partial doesn't get rendered, unless I refresh the page.  What am I missing?

I've removed the partial from the equation and just replaced that line with a simple div instead and it's still not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to wrap the results in a turbo frame with an id of "events" like so:-

```
<turbo-frame id="events">
  <% if @events.any? %>
    <%= render "events", events: @events %>
  <% else %>
    <%= render "no_events" %>
  <% end %>
</turbo-frame>
```